# Use RAW Bitmap via ImageView.setImageUri()

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-contentprovider

I am trying to write a content provider in order to send an image to another process via ImageView.setImageUri() call, the Bitmap i want to send is in memory and, due to performance reasons, i would prefer avoiding saving it on disk and even encoding it because it might take up to 2/3 seconds to encode in PNG and it wouldn't make much sense since the other end is then decoding it.

So, i am able to send the image in PNG correctly using a PipeHelper but i cannot send it "raw" (so an Android Bitmap as a bytearray directly from memory), is there any option to do that? Am i passing the wrong mime type? Why setImageBitmap() works with raw bitmaps while setImageUri() doesn't?

I know i could use a Parcelable Bitmap but i want to overcome Parcelable size constraints. Finally, is there any encoding faster than PNG that supports alpha if ending size is not an issue?

Comment: "Why setImageBitmap() works with raw bitmaps while setImageUri() doesn't" what do you mean? Uri is Uri, not Bitmap... what do you mean by "raw"?

Comment: Off course URI is not a Bitmap but it will resolve to an outputstream that will provide the data. I mean a Bitmap without encoding, an uncompressed Bitmap, a bytearray. An Android Bitmap (question updated, thanks).

Comment: so use `copyPixelsToBuffer`

Comment: that's what i am doing, but if i provide that data in a stream back to ImageView.setImageUri() through the provider it will not be displayed by the imageview.

Comment: The problem relies in  BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(res, value, is, pad, opts), which is called from ImageView during content resolution, apparently if i pass as "is" just a bytearray of a decoded bitmap the bitmap is not decoded properly, so decode does not work for a decoded stream.

Comment: all BitmapFactory methods operate on encoded data, if you have a Bitmap why dont you want to `compress()` it ?

Comment: As i said in original post i do not want to do that because compressing it in PNG takes to much and i need alpha channel, so unless there is a faster alpha enabled compression algorithm i have no option.

Comment: so the only option is to create a Bitmap based on raw data `copyPixelsFromBuffer` -> raw pixels -> `copyPixelsToBuffer`

Comment: yes, but unfortunately i am using remoteviews without control on target imageview so i cannot do that :(

Comment: you have `setImageViewBitmap(int viewId, Bitmap bitmap)`

Comment: yes, but that has limitations in the size of the bitmap being sent over